# How can an NVIDIA vGPU VM determine the correct NVIDIA-grid driver version?

Tags: nvidia

NVIDIA GRID driver installation: https://docs.nvidia.com/grid/latest/grid-vgpu-user-guide/index.html#installing-vgpu-drivers-linux

I work with an environment where we have multiple hosts with Tesla cards, each serving slices of vGPU to client VMs, but with a small number of different versions of the NVIDIA GRID driver. We install the NVIDIA GRID driver automatically, but I want to go from "one size fits most" (where the majority driver is selected for installation and differences are fixed up manually), to a fully automated solution.

I cannot find in the NVIDIA documentation how to query the host computer to determine what that version should be. It seems like it should be through either `lspci`, `dmesg`, or `nvidia-smi` tools. But:

```
# lspci|grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GV100GL [Tesla V100 PCIe 16GB] (rev a1)
```

No clue there. `dmesg` only tells you a version when the module loads successfully, i.e. the version matches; and `nvidia-smi` tells us there *aren't* any cards until the version matches.

Is there some information fed to the client, or is this a lost cause? (i.e. tell the host maintainers to use a single consistent version)